# Give bootstrap columns more height < 768 px

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made 4 columns with bootstrap 3. Every column is `400x220px`. I would do anything for make those columns `300x350px` when the viewport hit `< 768px`. I do not know an method for doing this, and as I can see Bootstrap cannot do it.

I could use the the html5 `<picture>` tag. But I cannot see I can integrate that with the Bootstrap 3 grid, and it would not be a good solution in my eyes.

Does anybody have another idea on how I could do this, or is it not possible?

[A demo of the columns is here](http://zalis.dk/example.html).

```css
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    /* Set width between grid elements */
    .small-padding.top {
       padding-top:10px;
    }

    .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
    } 
    .small-padding.left {
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .small-padding.right {
        padding-right:5px;
    }
    .margin_bottom {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .row {
      margin-left: -5px;
      margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .img-responsive { 
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Position of buttons/text in a single grid element */
    .inner-wrapper {
      text-align: center;
      background: none;
    }
    .centered {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .bottom-right {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        right: 16px;
    }

    .bottom-left {
        position: absolute;

        bottom: 8px;
        left: 16px;
    }
    /* Color on text */
    .dark-font {
      color: #333;
    }
    .light-font {
      color: #fff;
    }
   
    /* Set full width on columns */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .img-responsive {
        width: 100%;
        }
      .btn-success {
        width: fit-content;
      }

    }

    @media (max-width: 991px) {
      h3 {
        font-size: 1.2em;

      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TEMPLATE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/400x220" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
             <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
              <h3>Here is headline 1</h3>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/400x220" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
             <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
                 <h3>Here is headline 2</h3>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/400x220" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
             <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-right">
                 <h3>Here is headline 3</h3>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 margin_bottom">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/400x220" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
             <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-right">
                 <h3>Here is headline 4</h3>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to your containers, give it a height... I think this is what you are asking for. If not, let me know!

```css
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
    }
    /* Set width between grid elements */
    .small-padding.top {
       padding-top:10px;
    }

    .small-padding.bottom {
        padding-bottom:10px;
    } 
    .small-padding.left {
        padding-left:5px;
    }

    .small-padding.right {
        padding-right:5px;
    }
    .margin_bottom {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .row [class*="col-"] {
      padding-right: 5px;
      padding-left: 5px;
    }
    .row {
      margin-left: -5px;
      margin-right: -5px;
    }
    .img-responsive { 
        height: 100%;
    }
    /* Position of buttons/text in a single grid element */
    .inner-wrapper {
      text-align: center;
      background: none;
    }
    .centered {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }

    .bottom-right {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 8px;
        right: 16px;
    }

    .bottom-left {
        position: absolute;

        bottom: 8px;
        left: 16px;
    }
    /* Color on text */
    .dark-font {
      color: #333;
    }
    .light-font {
      color: #fff;
    }
   
    /* Set full width on columns */
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .img-responsive { /*EDIT*/
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        }
      .btn-success {
        width: fit-content;
      }
      /* Here you go */
      .height-m {
        height: 350px;
      }

    }

    @media (max-width: 991px) {
      h3 {
        font-size: 1.2em;

      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>TEMPLATE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 margin_bottom height-m">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/400x220" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
             <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
              <h3>Here is headline 1</h3>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 margin_bottom height-m">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/400x220" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
             <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-left">
                 <h3>Here is headline 2</h3>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 margin_bottom height-m">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/400x220" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
             <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-right">
                 <h3>Here is headline 3</h3>
             </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 margin_bottom height-m">
             <img src="http://placehold.it/400x220" alt="5" class="img-responsive" />
             <div class="inner-wrapper bottom-right">
                 <h3>Here is headline 4</h3>
             </div>
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is actually doing exact what I wanted. But one thing I did not think of. The picture is of course going out of dimensions: http://zalis.dk/example.html. Is there a way to solve that? Could I do that with html `<picture>` tag? In case how could that be done?

Comment: Try setting the width back to 100%, height auto. The image will not fill your container unless the image is the same size.

Comment: On the height-m class?

Comment: No, I apologize. `.img-responsive` should be that. Also, accept the answer so others can see the solution if they encounter the same issue.

Comment: Sorry I am not getting it. I would be very happy if you had time to update the css for it, so I can see how it is looking.

Comment: I edited the answer. This will not distort the image, but also won't fill the whole container. In order to do that you will need an image that is the same size as the container.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177219/discussion-between-rileyjsumner-and-mk-dk).